# How to disable Null and Weak Ciphers on 389-Directory-Server

Tags: encryption, centos, directory-server

I am running 389-DS on CentOS. Version - '389-ds-base.i686 1.2.11.15-34.el6_5'.
Security scans revealed that NullCiphers were found on Port 389 and 636.

I tried to disable them by shutting down DS, editing the 'nsSSL3Ciphers' on all '/etc/dirsrv/slapd-/dse.ldif' files, and starting DS. nsSSL3Ciphers looks like this now -

```
modifyTimestamp: 20140915221826Z
nsSSL3Ciphers: -rsa_null_md5,+rsa_rc4_128_md5,+rsa_rc4_40_md5,+rsa_rc2_40_md5,
 +rsa_des_sha,+rsa_fips_des_sha,+rsa_3des_sha,+rsa_fips_3des_sha,+fortezza,+fo
 rtezza_rc4_128_sha,-fortezza_null,+tls_rsa_export1024_with_rc4_56_sha,+tls_rs
 a_export1024_with_des_cbc_sha
numSubordinates: 1
```

Scans are still showing Null Cipher on those 2 ports.

```
Here is the list of null SSL ciphers supported by the remote server :
  Null Ciphers (no encryption)
    TLSv1
      NULL-SHA                     Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=None                 Mac=SHA1   
The fields above are :
  {OpenSSL ciphername}
Port
389 / tcp / ldap    
636 / tcp / ldap
```

Any ideas on how i can disable these Null ciphers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set nsSSL3Ciphers to the following -

```
nsSSL3Ciphers: +all,-rsa_null_sha
```